# ec2 instance cpu type

Tags: amazon-ec2, intel, amd-processor

How do you select either AMD or Intel CPU for your new ec2 instance?

Comment: sounds easy but i wouldn't recommend this since you already pay for the first hour no matter if you used it or not, so this can be very costly (sorry, this is a respond to stivlo's answer)

Comment: @Adam Yes, it could cost you a few hours, and maybe you don't get any favorable result: it's a lottery. Supposing that you start 10 times a small instance in US east, it's $0.085 a shot. So if you try 10 times before giving up, you'd have spent $0.85, less than $1, it's not that much :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's not the point of cloud computing at all. One small instance is roughly a particular benchmark, a 1.7GHz Intel processor I believe. What runs to get that benchmark is up to Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

You can't select it. You can try to run an instance and see, if it doesn't have the CPU that you'd like, you can shut it down and try to start a new one, you can also try to change the Availability Zone.

Answer (score 0):

The instances that have guaranteed CPU types are the Cluster Compute instances, which you should be using if you are doing something numerical.